# Enable multiple selection of rows in NStableview

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I created a small application that is based on the structure of [this example](https://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html) application.
But now I need you to select multiple rows in tableview, I tried to find a solution but did not succeed. Could you tell me how should I do? Keep in mind that I am no expert. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the Interface Builder. 
Select your Table View, go in the attributes inspector under selection and check multiple selection.